# What's the best way of appending in a recursive method in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

In below code, I am trying to parse a string '1/2/3/4/5/6/' to a hierarchy tree, expect output should like this:

```
# 1 -> 2 
# 2 -> 3
# 3 -> 4
# 4 -> 5
# 5 -> 6
```

but it returns:

```
# 1 -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

After I print some variables, I found the reason, variable 'a1' not only for the first 'a1', but also stand for all variables named 'a1', every call method, it produce a 'a1' variable, and operate on it. Python doesn't like other OO language, 'a1' expected to be the only variable in currently call only. So my question is, what's the best way to solve this kind of problem in Python?

```
class A(object):
    name = ''
    children = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s -> %s' % (self.name, self.children)

def recurse(a1, s):
    if len(s) == 0: return

    s1 = s[0:s.find('/')]
    a1.name = s1
    print 's1: %s' % (s1)

    s2 = s[s.find('/') + 1:]
    print 's2: %s' % (s2)

    a2 = A()
    a1.children.append(a2) # Problem: why all child append into variable 'a' and all children too?
    # print 'locals() -> ', locals()    when I print locals(), I got the reason, but what's the best way to fix the problem?
    recurse(a2, s2)

a = A()
recurse(a, '1/2/3/4/5/6/') # input string required to ends with '/'

# expect: 
# 1 -> 2 
# 2 -> 3
# 3 -> 4
# 4 -> 5
# 5 -> 6

print a
```

Comment: Unless you are practicing recursion `s= '1/2/3/4/5/6/';p = s[0];for c in s.strip('/').split('/')[1:]:print "# %s -> %s" % (p,c);p = c` could do the same

Comment: You are using class variables. so the `a` outside of `recurse` and `a2` inside of `recurse` is sharing the `children`.Check if it was intentional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your children is a class attribute, so all the instances will be sharing and modifying the same list

```
class A(object): 
    name = ''                      # these are class
    children = []                  # attributes
```

You should give each instance it's own list

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''             # these are instance
        self.children = []         # attributes
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding each node as a child to the previous node, you obtain a chain relationship. You can make the function return a list of nodes instead:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s -> %s' % (self.name, self.children)

def recurse(s,l=[]):
    v = s.split("/")
    if len(v) < 3: return
    a1,a2 = A(v[0]), A(v[1])
    a1.children.append(a2)
    v.pop(0)
    l.append(a1)
    recurse("/".join(v),l)
    return l

for i in recurse('1/2/3/4/5/6/'):
    print i
```

*Output:*

```
1 -> [2 -> []]
2 -> [3 -> []]
3 -> [4 -> []]
4 -> [5 -> []]
5 -> [6 -> []]
```

Comment: I think the chain is the desired outcome. It only wasn't happening due to the shared class variable.